# Convert Java.util.date to User Friendly Date

Tags: php, date, converters

I would like to convert a `java.util.Date` to something more user friendly using PHP. Is there a way of doing this using PHP?

I tried doing something like:

```
$created = date("F j, Y, g:i a", $issue_fields['created_date']);
```

but it complained with an error that looks like:

```
Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\wamp\www\PHP\get_tickets.php on line 49
```

Unfortunately, I don't have control over the date format I received. The format looks like:

```
2013-01-22T11:46:24.000-0800
```

and I would like something more like September 24, 2011, 6:39 am. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php) - you are using `date()` incorrectly. It takes a unix epoch time as its second argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the given date is in ISO 8601 format.  You should be able to convert this to a date object using strtotime:

```
echo date("F j, Y, g:i a", strtotime('2013-01-22T11:46:24.000-0800'));
```

This yields: January 22, 2013, 11:46 am

Comment: And you my friend are awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [date_parse_from_format()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php).

Comment: @BrianRoach You must have a different idea of what he wants than me then. He wants to parse a date/time string, as I understand it. Converting it to another format is another step, but one that should be fairly obvious once he reads the docs.

Comment: Actually reading his question led me to that idea. His *entire question* is asking how to convert one to another.